# Dell PowerEdge T710, add a new hard disk, how to?

Tags: dell-poweredge, diskmanagement

I have a virtual machine which needs more space. This VM runs and a PowerEdge T710 with Vmware EXSI 4.  I would like to add this disk in the simplest was possible.

I already got a normal desktop hard disk (SATA, 1TB, not Dell branded).
I have no rack for it to plug it inside any of the front bays.

I found an available SATA cable and power. Can I just add the disk by plugging these and using the empty 5"1/4 slot available under the CD drive (with a 5"1/4 - 3½" bay adapter)?

Even if this way it seems that I bypass the RAID controller that owns the front bay with racks.

edit : i suppose the existing RAID is composed of 1 TB drive, BTW this is ok for lack of redundancy, i accept if for now. My difficulties are : can i plug it this (loosy) way ? will it be seen by the firmware/BIOS and VMWare and also how to setup and install the drive so that BIOS + VMWare recognize it and add it as a new ressource (what are the particular steps to follow?)

[image: screenshot of the EXSI]

Answer (score 4):

I have no Vmware EXSI 4 experience, but from a hardware point of view:

1) Yes, you can add the drive that way. It will not be part of any existing RAID arrays. It will not have redundancy. But the PowerEdge will be able to access it and if the drivers of ESX4 allow it you can also use it as a direct usable disk (passthough) from the VM.

I repeat: No redundancy. If the drive fails you just lost all data on it.

2) If you are using hardware RAID with SAS drives then you can not add it to the existing array.

3) Do contract Dell for a proper 5 1/4  - 3½" bay adapter. Or check Ebay. Lose drives in a server are not recommended. :)

Could you check which drives are already in the server. Type, speed, interface. Then add that to the post. (Just in case the HW RAID consists of 1TB SATA drives)

Comment: ok for the "if drive fail" i had to accept that for now, my main troubles is that from my trial, i can not see the disk added as a manageable/usage "ressource", actually i do not know what are the steps after plugging the power and sata wires... (real beginner)

Comment: For that you will have to search in the vmware manual. I can tell you for windows, GNU/Linux, BSD, ... but as stated not for ESX4. No experience with that.